# Using regex to select AFTER one line all the way to a specific word on another line

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm not sure if this is possible. I have a list with specific words on new lines, and I need to select the words between those lines. For example my source is:

```
Word_1
Word_2
Location
Variable_1
Variable_2
Variable_3
Section
Word_9
```

I need regex to find the line after Location, which I am doing using `(.*(?<=\bLocation\s)(\w+).*)|.*` and replacing with `$1`. However this only gives me Variable_1 and I need it to give me `Variable_1,Variable_2,Variable_3`. And here's the catch, sometimes there is one Variable, sometimes 2, sometimes 3, sometimes 4. BUT, the following word will always be Section. So I'm thinking I need basically some way to tell Regex to select every line after Location but before Section.

Any ideas?

Real world example:

```
Category
Business
Dates
StatusOpen
Closing Information
Location
National
South-East Asia
New South Wales
Victoria
Sections
General
Difficulty Rating
Administrator
```

Output would be `National,South-East Asia,New South Wales,Victoria`

Comment: What language or app are you working in?

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can use DOTALL in your re.

```
print(re.findall("Location(.*)Section",string,re.DOTALL)[0])
```

Output:

```
Variable_1
Variable_2
Variable_3
```

For PHP can you try the below.

```
'\w*Location(.*)Section/s'
```

You can check the output in this link for your example.

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/mOkzpd/1)

Output match:

```
National
South-East Asia
New South Wales
Victoria
```

Comment: Can't use Python unfortunately. Thanks though.

Comment: which language are you using it?

Comment: It's in a wordpress plugin I am assuming it's just general notepad++ type find and replace.

Comment: wordpress is php based. So you should use php regex functions fine.

Comment: Lemme clear your question, you need to select the words that don't have any _, right? Such as Location and Section

Comment: I need to select every line between Location and Section, but not Location and Section, and I don't know how many lines it will be, and then comma seperate them.

Comment: This example "Variable_1" always will be like that structure? "Letters_number"?

Comment: No it will be a string. Could be one word, could be multiple, no underscores, I was just using that as an example sorry. But it will have each value on a seperate line, the value will be a word or sentence.

Comment: can you provide a real example? The input data and the desired result of it would be great!

Comment: I edited my original post with a real world example.

Comment: I have updated my answer with PHP code. Please use it and see if it solves your purpose.

Comment: @Mike how about you use a php solution instead of regex? I'm gonna do something for you.

Comment: It's in a built in wordpress plugin that allows you to use find/replace regex to sort through/refine data. So has to be the way it has to be unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with PHP would be:

```
<?php

$string =
"Category
Business
Dates
StatusOpen
Closing Information
Location
National
South-East Asia
New South Wales
Victoria
Sections
General
Difficulty Rating
Administrator";

$initialValue = false;
$lastValue = false;
$arResult = [];
$arValue = explode("\n", $string);

foreach($arValue as $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if ($value == "Location") {
        $initialValue = true;
    } else if ($value == "Sections") {
        $lastValue = true;
    } else if ($initialValue == true && $lastValue == false) {
        $arResult[] = $value;
    }
}

echo implode(",",$arResult); // National,South-East Asia,New South Wales,Victoria
```